# Todo-Tree: Cannot read property 'fsPath' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using VSCode with the ToDo Tree Plugin.
When I try to add a Todo in my code the plugin generates the following error:
Cannot read property 'fsPath' of undefined.

Does anybody know how to solve it ?
Any help highly appreciated.
pk

Answer (score -1):

This type of problem is related to updating VS Code. The Plugin needs to receive an update path. Report the bug to the plugin's develop